# How to show datepicker widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I have the following code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.layouts import column as bokehCol
from bokeh.models.layouts import Column
from bokeh.models.widgets import DatePicker
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta as td
from datetime import datetime as dt
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import show

output_notebook()

crnt_date=dt.now()

dt_pckr_strt=DatePicker(title='Select start of sync date',min_date=date(2017,1,1),max_date=date.today())

def callback(attr,old,new):
    print(type(old))
    print('old was {} and new is {}'.format(old,new))

dt_pckr_strt.on_change('value',callback)
curdoc().add_root(bokehCol(dt_pckr_strt))
show(widgetbox(dt_pckr_strt, width=300))
```

The output is showing weird instead of conventional datepicker. I believe it's in show function I am doing some mistake. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me (fixed the issue about embedding the Bokeh Server into Jupyter Notebook)

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.layouts import column as bokehCol
from bokeh.models.layouts import Column
from bokeh.models.widgets import DatePicker
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta as td
from datetime import datetime as dt
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler

output_notebook()

def modify_doc(doc):

    crnt_date=dt.now()

    dt_pckr_strt=DatePicker(title='Select start of sync date',min_date=date(2017,1,1),max_date=date.today())


    def callback(attr,old,new):
        print(type(old))
        print('old was {} and new is {}'.format(old,new))



    dt_pckr_strt.on_change('value',callback)

    doc.add_root(bokehCol(dt_pckr_strt))


app = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))
show(app) #notebook_url="localhost:8888"
```

[image]

Comment: It says `Application not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong (more or less -- if you want to use real python callbacks e.g. `on_change` you will have to embed a *Bokeh Server Application*, but that's a separate issue). However, it appears that something about the notebook environment is preventing the Bokeh date picker widget from functioning properly. The same code in a standalone HTML file created with `output_file` has a working date picker. I would suggest filing a bug report on the [Bokeh issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with all this information. Unfortunately I don't have any simple workarounds to suggest at this time.